# CSS: imagen flotando sobre otra imagen sin afectar la posición

Tags: html, jquery, css

Necesito hacer que la imagen de edición permanezca por encima de la imagen, por ejemplo, gmail, sin afectar el tamaño o el margen de la imagen de gmail, la imagen de edición debería aparecer cuando el mouse pasa sobre la imagen de gmail, ¿algún ejemplo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este foro se usa el castellano como idioma, si quieres mantener la pregunta en inglés publícala en la versión inglesa de stackoverflow, si quieres mantenerla aquí tradúcela a castellano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.Gmail {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.Gmail:hover .edit {
    display: block;
}

.edit {
    padding-top: 7px;   
    padding-right: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.edit a {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hover to Edit Profile Pic</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Hover Over Image to Display Edit Icon</h2>
    <div class="Gmail">
        <img src="https://www.mundocuentas.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/gmail-logo-mundocuentas.jpg"  width = "200px">
        <div class="edit"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a></div>
    </div>
        <div class="edit"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes jugar con la propiedad `position: absolute;` que te permite sacar del contexto normal el elemento y posicionarlo en relación al contenedor padre. Tienes que añadir la `position: relative` al contenedor para que el elemento se posicione en relación a él.

[Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.edit-img{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease opacity;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


 .container:hover .edit-img {
   opacity:1;
   transition: .3s ease opacity;
 }

 .container {
    width:  300px;
    border:  1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
 }

 .google-img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
 }
</style>
<body>

<div class="container" >
<img src="https://d3t4nwcgmfrp9x.cloudfront.net/upload/funciones-ocultas-mas-importantes-de-gmail.jpg" class="google-img"  width="100px"/>

<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glyphpack/45/edit-alt-512.png" class="edit-img"  width="40px"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```